# Laravel controller insert two id columns at save()

Tags: sql, laravel, controller, null, insert

I am trying to add two columns: `id` and `category_id` and I need both to be the same value

```
        $category = new HmsBbrCategory;
        $category->id = increments();
        $category->category_id = id+1;
        $category->category_name = $request->input('category_name');
        $category->category_description = $request->input('category_description');
        $category->save();
        return response()->json([
            'status'=>200,
            'message'=>'Category Added!',
           
        ]);
```

[image: 1]

as you can see, both columns return null, tried adding two lines but of course they do not work:

```
        $category->id = increments();
        $category->category_id = id+1;
```

both values have no form, I just need them auto incremented and the same. What should I change here to add a value in the table thats not taken from a input field?

**UPDATE**

As suggested I incremented the id but my console error keeps saying my category_id is null:

```
        $category = new HmsBbrCategory;
        $category->category_name = $request->input('category_name');
        $category->category_description = $request->input('category_description');
        $category->save();
        $category->category_id = $category->id;
        $category->save();
```

**console error:**

```
Failing row contains (3, null, 4, 4).
```

is it because the save function tries to insert it at `category_id` that needs not be not null?

Update:

I set the `category_id` column as not required to be not null, but the columns are still null even when the `save()` and `update` is added as suggested.

```
$category->update(['category_id '=> $category->id]);

$category->category_id = $category->id;
$category->save();
```

[image: 2]

**MODEL:**

```
  protected $fillable = [ "id", "category_id", "category_name", "category_description" ];
```

**FULL CONTROLLER**

```
class BBRCategoryConfigurationController extends Controller {
public function index(){
    return view('frontend.bbr-settings.bbr-category-configuration');
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'category_name'=>'required|max:191',
        'category_description'=>'required|max:191',
    ]);
    if($validator->fails())
    {
        return response()->json([
            'status'=>400,
            'errors'=>$validator->messages(),
        ]);
    }
    else {
        $category = new HmsBbrCategory;
        $category->category_name = $request->input('category_name');
        $category->category_description = $request->input('category_description');
        $category->save();
        $category->update(['category_id '=> $category->id]);
        
        return response()->json([
            'status'=>200,
            'message'=>'Category Added!',
           
        ]);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: try this. 
$category->category_id = $category->id+1;

Comment: its not adding, i think the mistake is in my increments(), not sure the way around the right syntax though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `id` as `auto increment` in your `database table` then do the following

```
$category = new HmsBbrCategory;
$category->category_name = $request->input('category_name');
$category->category_description = $request->input('category_description');
$category->save();

$category->category_id = $category->id;
$category->save();
```

or
For this make sure to fieldname is fillable

```
$category = new HmsBbrCategory;
    $category->category_name = $request->input('category_name');
    $category->category_description = $request->input('category_description');
    $category->save();
   
 $category->update(['category_id '=> $category->id]);
```

Comment: using save() twice will be ok?

Comment: its not save twice its update to existing record

Comment: tried this, i am getting Failing row contains (2, null, e, e). on the console (id, category_id, name, desc)

Comment: the table is already shown in my screenshots

Comment: oaky.can you show full method code atleast so we can see what happens

Comment: im, not sure which part am i still missing, ive shown the error....its returning null at category_id

Comment: so  i asked.can you post full method from controller and post model as well so we can check anythink causing

Comment: hi dont use both method together $category->update(['category_id '=> $category->id]);

$category->category_id = $category->id;
$category->save();

Comment: use any one of the method

Comment: sry, it still outputs null, still thanks for all the input though, not sure why the column is not updating to the id's value

Comment: ah, i got it, seems like the save() version works. thanks!